# What's the Time Complexity and Space Complexity this function to check valid parenthesis?

Tags: c++, algorithm, time-complexity, space-complexity

I am unable to find the Time Complexity and Space Complexity of the code to check valid parenthesis. Can anyone help, please?

code -

```
bool isValid(string s) 
{
        int s_size = s.length();
        for (int i = 0; i < s_size-1;i++)
        {
            if((s[i]=='(' && s[i+1]==')') || (s[i]=='[' && s[i+1]==']')|| (s[i]=='{' && s[i+1]=='}'))
            {
                s.erase(i, 2);
                i=-1;
                s_size-=2;
            }

        }
        if(s.empty())
            return true;
        else 
            return false;
                
    }
```

I think the space complexity is O(1) and the time complexity is O(n). Correct me please, if I am wrong.

Comment: Does [this](https://godbolt.org/z/1jG5Mor3W) look like O(n) to you? [Reference](https://oeis.org/A000217).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For just the code snippet you posted above, the time complexity is O(n<sup>3</sup>).

As rightly pointed out by [n. 'pronouns' m.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/775806/n-pronouns-m), the outer for loop `for (int i = 0; i < s_size-1;i++)` runs n<sup>2</sup> times because `i` resets to the starting point every time a match is found. And the `s.erase()` function also takes O(n) time to run. In total making up for a cubic O(n<sup>3</sup>) time complexity.

You can read up on `std::string.erase()` function [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/erase/)

You are right about space complexity. Its O(1).

To solve the above problem of **Valid Parenthesis** efficiently i.e., within O(n) time complexity and O(n) space complexity, consider using a stack.

Comment: Actually the outer loop takes O(n^2) because the loop variable is reset every time a match is found.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. Ahh! I see now. But that I think is a typo. He imo intended to write `i-=1`

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. Okay I get it now. I will edit my answer rightaway

Comment: No wait, I think it could work correctly if you change it this way. Need to test though.